# Classlist method gives typerror

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make a simple to do list and I'm trying select all the li tags so when clicked on the li tag it would cross it out and display a check mark But I get an error saying **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
at check (script.js:11:18)
at HTMLLIElement.onclick (index.html:12:33)**

```js
const addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
const inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
const li = document.getElementsByClassName("li")

addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    myUl.innerHTML += `<li>${inputEl.value}</li>`
})

check = () => {
    li.classList.add("checked")

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  /* Remove margins and padding from the list */
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /* Style the list items */
  ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.2s;
  
    /* make the list items unselectable */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  /* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
  ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
  }
  
  /* Darker background-color on hover */
  ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
  }
  
  /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
  ul li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  
  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
  ul li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
  }
  
  /* Style the close button */
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
  }
  
  .close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
  }
  
  /* Style the header */
  .header {
    background-color: #f44336;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the header */
  .header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  /* Style the input */
  input {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  /* Style the "Add" button */
  #addBtn {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    color: #555;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  .addBtn:hover {
    background-color: #bbb;
  }
```

```html
<h2>My To Do List</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<span id="addBtn">Add</span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
<li  onclick="check()">Hit the gym</li>
<li class="checked">Pay bills</li>
<li onclick="check()">Meet George</li>
<li  onclick="check()">Buy eggs</li>
<li  onclick="check()">Read a book</li>
<li  onclick="check()">Organize office</li>
</ul>
<script src="script.js">

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list (collection) of matching elements. `classList` is a property of a single element. In order to use it, you must call it on one element only.

Alternatives:

1. Use `.querySelector(.[className])` to return the first element that
   matches the selector.
2. Access one of the collection items by passing an index (`li[0]`).
3. Loop over the collection and call classList on each item as you
   loop.

Also, [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()` in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) as it returns a "live node list" that causes performance issues.